# Htaccess rewrite rules subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i'm quite new in the world of Url Rewriting. I have to do so into our own CMS to have a good looking url and to get a better structure that gives results with search engine (SEO).

This is the background file that do all the job that we now hide with nice URL's:

- http://something.com/fr/index.php

This is an example of my structure pattern :

- http://something.com/fr/accueil or ...
- http://something.com/fr/produits/solives-de-rive-rimboard

The CMS simply create an HTACCESS file into the FR directory for quite basic rewriterule like the following :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule produits/solives-de-rive-rimboard index.php?p=144
RewriteRule produits/decoupe-sur-mesure index.php?p=145
RewriteRule produits/panneaux-osb index.php?p=146
RewriteRule produits/boites-de-bois-crates index.php?p=147
RewriteRule produits/palettes-de-bois index.php?p=148
RewriteRule accueil index.php?p=4
RewriteRule a-propos-de-cimdat index.php?p=139
RewriteRule produits index.php?p=140
RewriteRule videos index.php?p=141
RewriteRule nous-joindre index.php?p=142
```

All works fine for first level page like "accueil", "nous-joindre"...

but I haven't found the work around for page of second and third level like "produits/solives-de-rive-rimboard". The index.php just load fine except that all relative link to this page are a subfolder away (the css, the image, jquery...).

Is there any tag that I can use into the htaccess file to specify that no matter in which level "accueil", "produits/something", or a third level one like "produits/group/something" for the index.php have a basic path ?

I'll prefer looking a work around within the htaccess instead of giving index.php a "`<base href="something">`" that might give us other problems in our structure.

Thanks

Comment: Those are the substitution URLs, the real ones. But how are the requested URL? At least one example to figure out the pattern. In other words, if possible give an example of the URL entered in the browser address bar and the corresponding rewritten URL to be redirected to.

Comment: Doh sorry for url substitution ... 

Just updated my initial post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTML issue, rather than a server or .htaccess problem. If your browser sees something like /category/product it is going to act as if it is in the /category/ folder regardless of where the internal server side redirects are sending the request.

The fix to this is simple, change all of the linking in your html to be relative to the site root. So if you have an image tag like

```
<img src="img/button.gif" />
```

change it to

```
<img src="/img/button.gif" />
```

This tells the browser the exact path from the root to request files from regardless of your rewrite rules. This needs to be done for all of your relative links, including css and javascripts. It may be a bit of work to do, but once it is done it should make future maintenance much easier since you won't have to worry about the apparent path to the page.

Yes, this could be done via .htaccess fairly simply, but there are side effects, including the fact that search engines could see it as duplicate content and it could increase your server bandwidth use as users can't cache static content efficiently. Your best bet is to follow the best practice now while the site is new and growing than try to fix it later after a workaround has caused problems.

Comment: @Jaune This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) will help you to modify the links easily.